# Request not defined in Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am simply trying to send data to Stripe to process a customer.  But the request is not defined? How is this possible?

Error:

13:52:17 web.1  | /Users/admin/herokutest/app/routes.js:139

13:52:17 web.1  | var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;

13:52:17 web.1  | ReferenceError: req is not defined

App.js File:

```
var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;

function subscribeUser(token, res){
    stripe.customers.create({
        card: stripeToken,
        plan: 'standard',
        email: 'test@test.test'
    }, function(err, customer) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({ok: false, message: 'Uh oh. there was a problem processing your card (error: ' + JSON.stringify(err) + ')'});
        } else {
            res.send({ok: true, message: 'Perfect, you have been subscribed to a plan'}),
            res.render('subscribe', { title: 'Congratulations!' })
        }
    });
}

app.post('/getstarted3', function (req, res) {
  subscribeUser();
  res.render('subscribe', { title: 'Welcome' }); // load the index.jade file    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;` is not in the correct scope, you have it outside of a request handler.

Also, you're not passing any arguments to your `subscribeUser()` and you are trying to respond to the same request multiple times. My guess is you want something like this:

```
function subscribeUser(token, res){
    stripe.customers.create({
        card: token,
        plan: 'standard',
        email: 'test@test.test'
    }, function(err, customer) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({ok: false, message: 'Uh oh. there was a problem processing your card (error: ' + JSON.stringify(err) + ')'});
        } else {
            res.send({ok: true, message: 'Perfect, you have been subscribed to a plan'}),

            // you can't respond to a request twice, it's one or the other ...
            //res.render('subscribe', { title: 'Congratulations!' })
        }
    });
}

app.post('/getstarted3', function (req, res) {
  subscribeUser(req.body.stripeToken, res);

  // you can't respond multiple times to the same request
  //res.render('subscribe', { title: 'Welcome' }); // load the index.jade file    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`req` is not declared in the scope of the whole file. The only place it's declared is in the argument list `function (req, res)`, and that only creates a variable scoped inside the function definition. You probably meant to change the next line to this:

```
  subscribeUser(req.body.stripeToken);
```

and then change the other function definition to this:

```
function subscribeUser(stripeToken){ ...
```